# thread exiting with uncaught exception - but app still runs as designed

Tags: android, multithreading

When installing my app to the emulator from Eclipse, I *sometimes* get an error in the log "thread exiting with uncaught exception".  Other SO posts refer to this, but the "cause" is usually a an activity built by the developer.  My cause seems to be some Android class.  I've tried Project>Clean, but that hasn't changed anything.  Also, the app runs fine, even if this error shows up.  There doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason to its appearance.  Thoughts?

Log here:

```
04-09 21:22:49.487: W/dalvikvm(1462): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
04-09 21:22:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1462): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 21:22:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1462): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.blobtag2.GlobalAppContext: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-09 21:22:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:501)
04-09 21:22:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4124)
04-09 21:22:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
04-09 21:22:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
04-09 21:22:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-09 21:22:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-09 21:22:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-09 21:22:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 21:22:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-09 21:22:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-09 21:22:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-09 21:22:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 21:22:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1462): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-09 21:22:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:377)
04-09 21:22:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:320)
04-09 21:22:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:493)
04-09 21:22:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     ... 11 more
```

EDIT - Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.blobtag2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name=".GlobalAppContext"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <service android:name=".service.RESTService" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ResultsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_results_activity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.blobtag2.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PlaceActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_place_activity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.blobtag2.ResultsActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

globalappcontext code:

```
public class GlobalAppContext extends Application {
private static VenueList venueList;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    venueList = new VenueList();
}

public static VenueList getVenueList() {
    return venueList;
}

/*do I still need this, since I have it in the venueList class?
public static void setPlaceName(String s) {
    venueList = s;
}
**/
}
```

Comment: Post your manifest, with at least the `<application>` tag

Comment: Do you have a class called `GlobalAppContext`?  It's null pointering because the class loader can't find that class.

Comment: Yes, GlobalAppContext exists and is in the root folder with the majority of my other classes.  How do I make class loader find it?  As you can see, it's noted in the manifest as well.

Comment: Do you have code in the constructor for `GlobalAppContext`?  Failing to instantiate the class means its failing during construction of the object by the framework.

Comment: yes, there's code.  unfortunately i won't have my personal computer and eclipse in front of me til this evening, but i will post it for you when i get back.

Comment: Not sure when you'll return, but check the code in your `GlobalAppContext` class constructor.  You might want to try to debug and step through the code where you might be getting a null pointer

Comment: i've put GlobalAppContext code above.  I was mistaken, I am using onCreate but no traditional constructor.  I'm not sure where to go.  When I create a normal constructor, it says "the method GlobalAppContext() of type GlobalAppContext must override or implement a supertype method"

Answer (score 0):

Change GlobalAppContext.java to:

```
public class GlobalAppContext {

    private static VenueList mVenueList = null;

    //----------------------------
    // Uses the Singleton method of Bill Pugh.
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern
    //----------------------------

    // --- Singleton code
    private GlobalAppContext() { }

    private static class GlobalAppContextHolder {
        public static final GlobalAppContext INSTANCE = new GlobalAppContext();
    }

    public static GlobalAppContext getInstance() {
        if (mVenueList == null) {
            mVenueList = new VenueList();
        }
        return GlobalAppContext.INSTANCE;
    }
    // --- End Singleton code

    public static VenueList getVenueList() {
        return mVenueList;
    }
}
```

And to call this global class with something like the following:

```
... snip ....
private static GlobalAppContext mGlobal = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (mGlobal == null) {
        mGlobal = GlobalAppContext.getInstance();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
}
```

And now you can access "VenueList" like this:

```
VenueList venueList = mGlobal.getVenueList();
```